# Use references in views

Tags: u-sql

I thinking of putting a logical layer on top of all raw files that comes in to data lake store.

I would like to have a view that combines all files that are the same "type" but are divided into date folders. I was thinking of doing this with a view and a dynamic folder path.

The problem that I have is that the files are avro and json file and for this I need assemblies. Is there a way that I can refrence the the asseblies in the views?

Or is it possible to do in an other way? suc as using table value functions etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query expression inside the USQL View at the moment do not allow any User Defined Objects and you cannot REFERENCE any assemblies within a USQL View definition.

You may be better with parametrized view (i.e. Table value functions) - you don't have to necessarily have a parameter. TVF provides great flexibility, for example if you want get just a Month or year worth of data - you could use USQL [filesets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621294.aspx) and pass in parameters.